# inotify: Script Running Twice

Tags: linux, bash

The following bash script running twice on File Change, however I am chaning one File at a time.

```
count=1

inotifywait -qm --event modify --format '%w' /Drives/My_Drive/Rapid/containerized_personal_tasks_automation/environment_setup/* | while read -r file ; do
    echo "Files Modified ${count}"
    ((count ++))
done
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **How** do you *modify* the files?

Comment: From my other Laptop (Windows), I am modifyig Files using VSCODE, then WINSCP will trigger changes to Other Laptop which is running with Linux OS. On Linux, this script will run and perform necessarry action based on Logic. However, Script is running twice on File Changes.